# Event rate for nuclear collisions covariant form

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, nuclear-physics, collision, large-hadron-collider

The event rate on a target of atomic mass $A$, with cross section per nucleus $\sigma$ is given by:
$$dR=\dfrac{N_{A}}{A}\sigma\,mv\,dn$$
where $N_{A}$ is the Avogadro number, $m$ and $v$ are the mass and velocity of the incoming particle and $dn$ is the number density of incoming particles.

This formula can be found in many articles and reviews ([for example](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0927-6505(96)00047-3)) concerning dark matter collisions with nuclear matter, but it is non-relativistic.

How can it be generalized in order to contain only Lorentz invariant terms? I mean, since the cross-sections are usually given in terms of the momentum $p_{\mu}$ and contractions $p_{\mu}p^{\mu}$, it is better to integrate $dR$ in momentum space and not writing in terms of the velocities $v.$